# Java serialization for cucumber test

Tags: java, cucumber, serialization, cucumber-java

Hello I have a cucumber test that looks like this

```
Given new "CucumberTest"    
| startDate               | endDate                 |
| 01/03/2016 08:00:00:UTC | 05/03/2016 17:00:00:UTC |
```

The test code looks something like this

```
@Given("^new "([^"]*)"$")
public void test(@Format(DateFormta) List<Travel> travels) {
   ...
}
```

Now the Travel class has `int id`, `Date startDate`, `Date endDate` fields.
I would like to change travel time by the country in which person is traveling. So lets say the server is in `UTC+2` time zone, and travel is in `UTC+1` zone. When I run the application it adds me 2 hours to my start and end date in my cucmber test code, but I need it to add only one. Is it possible to use java serializer or deserializer for it to automatically to change?

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()
       .toString()
```

…and…

```
Instant.now()
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )
       .toString()
```

## Do not use `java.util.Date`

You are using `java.util.Date` class? That is part of the troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## java.time

Use `Instant` for a moment on the timeline in UTC. Equivalent to `Date` but with a resolution of nanoseconds instead of milliseconds (and many other improvements).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats by default when generating/parsing strings.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

> 2017-01-23T12:34:56.987654321Z

The `Z` on the end is short for `Zulu` and mean UTC.

Never rely on the default time zone or offset. You may not have control at deployment time. Worse, any code in any thread of any app within your JVM can change the current default *during* runtime.

Always specify your desired/expected time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Berlin" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Always use time zones when known rather than mere offset-from-UTC. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future offsets used by a particular region.

Always use true name of time zones, in `continent/region` format.

Comment: Yes I know that java.util.date is an outdated thing, but the problem is that I need to use it because the project is legacy...